# Computations over a normal Ultrapower

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a normal measure on $\kappa$ and let $j = j_\mathcal{U} : V\rightarrow M = M_\mathcal{U}$ be the corresponding ultrapower.

Prove that $\sup\{j(\alpha)\  \big|\ \alpha<\kappa^+\}$, conclude that $\{j(\alpha)\  \big|\ \alpha<\kappa^+\} \notin M$ and thus $M$ cannot be closed under $\kappa^+$-sequences of ordinals.

My try:

Let $f:\kappa\rightarrow\kappa^+$   be some function then since $\mathrm{cf}\ \kappa^+ = \kappa^+ > \kappa$ we know that $\exists\alpha<\kappa^+$ s.t

$$\forall\beta<\kappa, f(\beta) < \alpha = c_\alpha(\beta)$$

thus $[f] < j(\alpha)$. Since the above is true for every such $f$  and the ordinals below $j(\kappa^+)$ are represented by functions of the form $\kappa\rightarrow \kappa^+$  it follows that

$$\forall [f]<j(\kappa^+),\ [f]<\sup \{ j(\alpha) \big|\  \alpha<\kappa^+ \}$$

thus $\sup \{ j(\alpha) \big|\  \alpha<\kappa^+ \}=j(\kappa^+)$

What I can't figure out is the second part, why $\{ j(\alpha) \big|\  \alpha<\kappa^+ \} \notin M$?

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: For the second question, if your sequence is in $M$, then the cofinality of $j(\kappa^+)$ is $\kappa^+$, but $M$ thinks $j(\kappa^+)$ is regular and $\kappa^+<j(\kappa^+)$.